# How to configure Mac screen sharing to ONLY listen on localhost?

Tags: screen-sharing, macos

I'm tunneling through ssh, so I would prefer screen sharing to only listen on local host for additional security. Is there a configure file I can edit to specify that ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to execute this in Terminal:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.RemoteManagement.plist VNCOnlyLocalConnections -bool yes
```

Comment: Im assuming changing the bool value to no reverses it ?